# How to enable tcp_keepalive for upstream connections in envoy proxy

Tags: tcp, grpc, envoyproxy

I am using setup where client -> envoy_proxy -> server.
My config.yaml for envoy proxy has following settings:

```
clusters:
  - name: cluster1"
    connect_timeout: 300s
    upstream_connection_options:
      tcp_keepalive:
        keepalive_probes: 1 
        keepalive_interval: 60
        keepalive_time: 10
    http2_protocol_options:
      connection_keepalive: {
        interval: 60s,
        timeout: 10s,
        connection_idle_interval: 10s
      }
```

With this setting, I expect upstream module i.e. grpc server will receive keep_alive pings after every 60 seconds. However, server is not receiving any ping. I am running grpc server with `GRPC_VERBOSITY=debug GRPC_TRACE=tcp,http` prefix. With these variables, I am hoping to get logs  related to keep-alive on the server. But with using envoy proxy, there are no keep-alive logs. However, when I connect client directly to grpc server, I do keep-alive logs on the server.